# How to create user in Firebase only if database fields are valid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After reading many articles about additional user data fields (in my case it's just unique username) in Firebase ecosystem, I approached the best (I hope) variant of saving and validating username - use the username as a node key under `/users/`.

I'm validating username on the client side and inside database rules:
`": "$user.matches(/^[0-9A-Z]{3,18}$/i)&& newData.hasChildren(['uid']) && !data.parent().hasChild($user)",`

I'm facing problems when signing user up. In my SignUp method I save username to the database in successful promise resolve of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method, here's a piece of code:

```
...
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
.then((user) => {
  // saving additional user information
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`users/${payload.username}`)
    .set({
      uid: user.uid,
    })
    .then(() => {
...
```

Client side validations is good, but obviously not enough. My application works ok, but if we disable client side validation of the username and try to submit invalid username - user will be created without username at all.

The only solution I see is to create username node first, if creation was successful - try to sign user up, if signing up won't throw any errors - continue program execution, otherwise in `.catch` block just delete created node with the username. But it seems like a very dirty solution to me.

How can I solve this problem in elegant way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems quite dirty and inelegant to me too. What I'd propose to do is to not go with the rules method to validate the username. Because, as you pointed out - you have no way to know when the validation fails.

Instead, I'd suggest you to write a database trigger function in your Cloud Functions implementation. This function should be triggered when the "username" node is populated. In this, you can validate the username to ensure that it meets whatever criteria that you've set. If, the validation is successful, your client app could indicate that to the user and proceed further.

If the validation is unsuccessful, you could ask the user to input another username. You could even display a progress bar or something similar in the client while the validation process takes places.

However, I'd like to add that this might just be one of the ways in which this can be solved and is not necessarily the best way. Although I can't think of a better way, I am entirely open to explore a different method if something else comes up!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! However after first step when we have validated and created username node, we need to store it somewhere on client for adding `uid` to this node in future. On this step the username could be change to something invalid. We don't have a way to restrict the user write `uid` to the created node, and not to any other. (if I understand everything right). We also will need to deal with a case if user typed username and didn't proceed to actual registration. Of course we can delete all username nodes without `uid` time to time, but still seems dirty.
Thanks!

Comment: But what if we place entire user creation process to the cloud functions?

Comment: I think I understand the confusion. Look, the `uid` is a user attribute and is created at the time of `createUserWithEmailandPassword`. So, this `uid` should serve as the unique identification for your user and not the `username`.

Comment: So, for all intents and purposes, you should use the `uid` as the core to identify your individual users in the database. You can of course add the `username` too, but that should only be additional. The reason for this is that the user object also contains the `uid`. Thus, whenever you log in to the to client app, you can just retrieve the `uid` from the logged in user's `user` object. You really don't need to store the `username` or the `uid` on the client side! It's also dangerous from security perspective.

Comment: But how do we query username if we don't associate uid with username?

Comment: Do associate `uid` with `username`! But the `uid` should be the parent and not vice versa. Like for example, your database could have the following structure - Users :{ "uid1" : {username : "abc"}} and so on.

Comment: And, of course the `username` should only be created after the `createUserWithEmailandPassword`'s promise is returned. My answer does that.

Comment: But hey, you don't have to take my word for it! You can research it further if and come to a solution that satisfies you. I'm just trying to help :D

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.UserInfo.html#uid

This makes it easy to identify the logged in user without needing to store any information on the client side.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems I was doing things very close to what you described above but moved from it to some wrong direction. Thanks :)
Hmm, maybe displayName would play username's role if it's unique.

Thanks, you helped a lot!

Comment: I don't store any information on client side. Just using normal firebase SDK practices for re-authenticate user after page reload in my SPA. :)
I was talking about storing username between registration steps, but nvm :)
Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! All the best :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you have required fields saved to the database, as well as no other 'not known' fields, you can use the .validate rule.
Add this to your database.rules.json (or directly in Database rules in the console):

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    "email": { ".validate": true },
    "displayName": { ".validate": true },
    "$other": { ".validate": false },

    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

Also, notice the recommended way to store a user in the Realtime Database, by using it's UID as the KEY.
So your user path will look like:

```
/users/9gZepE9jODX1KZGZ2EEyoX1NyOX4
```