# How to use promise in an argument function (Firebase transaction)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[Firebase transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) receives first argument as a function(any type). Can I use a method that returns promise inside this function? (in my case it's `firebase-admin.auth().createUser()`).

Some code for clarity:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref(...);
ref.transaction((currentData) => {
  if (currentData === null && ...) {
    admin
      .auth()
      .createUser({...})
      .then(data => return { uid: data.uid }) // Need to return this 'someData' from function that wraps current promise.
      .catch(() => return null)
  } else {
    return null
  }
});
```

In this code the function runs without waiting for promises to be resolved.

NodeJS v.6.11.1 (Google Cloud Functions)

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I'm expecting to return data from this argument-function only if promise resolves without errors (i.e. reaches `then`), thus applying transaction only if user created.

Comment: Where is `someData` defined? Why do you use `return` without `{}` within `.then()` at arrow function? Are you expecting a `Promise` or a `Boolean` to be returned from `validateUserData` call at `if (validateUserData(req.body)) {}`?

Comment: Hello, @guest271314!
I'm sorry, I was too abstract at the example code. Changed it to be closer to real.

validateUserData from the pastebin code supposed to return a `Boolean`.

Comment: Currently `validateUserData()` returns a `Promise`, yes? Have you considered including code at linked pastebin at OP and indicating what the expected result is?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm sorry, this code in pastebin wasn't well-tested and you're right, it returns unresolved promise which always evaluates to true. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises can't be used inside a transaction handler.  A transaction handler is required to immediately return the new contents of the database at the location of the transaction.

The call to [transaction()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#transaction) itself returns a promise, so if you want to do something after a successful transaction, you can use then() on that promise (which contains the success state of the transaction) and follow up with some additional actions that could also return a promise from there.

Right now, it doesn't look like you're making any changes at all to the database within the transaction, so I'm curious why you're even using one.

Comment: `.then(data => return { uid: data.uid })`
I want to create /users/{username} only if createUser was successfull.

Trying to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252458

Comment: `const userRef = admin.database().ref(\`users/${req.body.username}\`)`

Comment: You've got the order of events backwards.  You should be using an authentication trigger to do things in the database only when a new user was created. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Comment: But how can I provide username that user typed in input field next to email and password to this type of functions?

Comment: Please read the documentation I linked to, and possibly ask a different question based on your use of an authentication trigger rather than a database trigger.